# Quotients of subdirect products of transitive subgroups of $S_4$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

**Definition.** Let $G$ be a finite transitive subgroup of $S_n$ for some $n$. We say that a group $H$ is of generalized $G$-type if $H$ is isomorphic to a quotient of a subdirect product of a finite number of transitive subgroups of $G$.

My goal is to find necessary and sufficient conditions to determine if a given group is of generalized $S_4$-type.

I have been able to come up with some necessary conditions namely:

If a finite group $H$ is gen-$S_4$ then:

- 12 mod Exponent($H$) = 0,
- the 3-Sylow subgroups of $H$ are abelian,
- the 2-sylow subgroups of $H$ are generalized-$D_4$.

Further, if a finite group $H$ is gen-$D_4$ then

- 4 mod Exponent($H$) = 0,
- $H$ is of [nilpotency at most class 2](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Group_of_nilpotency_class_two).

Seeing that these are necessary is not too hard since each of the properties is preserved under taking direct product, quotients and subgroups.

What is left to show is that these conditions are in fact sufficient to conclude that a group is of generalized $S_4$-type. I have searched high and low and I can't find a counterexample, which leads me to believe that it is true, but I am also not sure how to prove that it is true.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Nilpotency class $2$ is not preserved under subgroups or quotients. You mean nilpotency class at most $2$.

Comment: My mistake. Thanks Derek!

Comment: You were right in the sense that people have been known to write nilpotency class $2$ meaning that the nilpotency class is at most $2$, but that sounds seriously confusing!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is true as it is. For example, if I understand your definition correctly, then in a gen-$D_4$ group, all elements of order $4$ commute (am I getting this right?), whereas there are groups of exponent $4$ and nilpotency class $2$ where this is not the case.

Very interesting question by the way. At first, I thought this was wildly implausible, but now I think that maybe something like it might be true.

Comment: So at first, this is what I thought too, but upon thinking about it longer I think there are examples of groups where the elements of order 4 do not commute.

**Example:** The quaternions are _not_ a subdirect product of transitive subgroups of $S_4$, but it is a quotient of such groups. Consider the subgroups of $S_4^2$

$G = \langle(1, 2, 3, 4)(5, 6)(7, 8), (5, 6, 7, 8), (1, 3)(2, 4), (5, 7)(6, 8)\rangle$

and 

$H = \langle(1, 3)(2, 4)(5, 7)(6, 8)\rangle.$

Then $G/H$ is isomorphic to $Q_8.$

Comment: I see. Here is an idea of an approach for a proof then. Try to see if the free group of nilpotency class at most 2 and exponent at most 4 on two generators is gen-D4. (This is a group of order 64, (64, 18) in the SmallGroup Library.) If not, then the statement is false, otherwise, try to use this fact and induction on the number of generators.

Comment: This is very interesting. Thank you so much for your help. One question: when I check the group G := SmallGroup(64,18) I get that it has exponent 8. Is it possible that the free group on two generators of nilpotency class 2 has a different label? Or does the free group not have exponent 4 and I should actually look at something like the free group of exponent 4 and nilpotency class 2.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake, it should have been SmallGroup(32,2).

Comment: By the way, my original comment seems very silly to me now. In your example, you don't even need to take quotients, $G$ already has elements of order $4$ that don't commute. In fact, $Z_4\times D_4$ has elements of order $4$ that don't commute.

Comment: This is really helpful. Just out of curiosity, how would I find the SmallGroup label for the free group on 3 generators of exponent 4 and nilpotency class 2? As for your "silly" comment, I think it really just points to the fact that this is a fairly subtle group theory question. I had the same first guess.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58539/discussion-between-verret-and-user1729).